# How to correctly populate href in the link tag?

Tags: javascript, html

If I am given a domain from user input say

```
domain.com
```

I must prepend it with either `http://`, `https://`, or `//` to make it work correctly.

What is the correct way to prepend this domain when inserting it into the DOM in a link tag?

I know it is first processed by the client and then the server can do re-directs of course if needed.

Comment: suggest using `http://` and don't use `//` for external site link if you are running on https. If remote site uses only https, they most likely have redirect from http set up on their server....if they don't have https, it may just fail when you redirect to it

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the a element. Then you can just concat the strings together when you set the href attribute. You can set the href attribute in a couple of ways:

**Using the href setter**

```
aElement.href = 'http://' + 'example.com';
```

**Using setAttribute**

```
aElement.setAttribute('href', 'http://' + 'example.com');
```